# Debugging a live ASP.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging

I have a C# ASP.net website.  Locally I can run it in debug and step through the code to see why things arent working but when its hosted on my live site I cannot do this.

What is the best way to debug what is going on with my website?

Should I add debut/output/trace statements?

If so, which and how do I view the output of these? Can I view them in Chrome-->Developer Tools somehow?

For example, right now I can register a user on my site so I know the database connection is good, but I cannot login a registered user and want to figure out why.

Thanks

Comment: `Trace` and DebugView are your friends, among a good logging framework.

Comment: How/Where do I view the output of these on a live website?

Comment: Does it make sense to debug or go thru the code of a live site?

Comment: Yes because I want to know why its not working.  It works locally on my PC but not when live.

Comment: Deploy the app to a fresh VM if you can, ideally one that is just like the live environment. You may find it is something silly that went wrong in deployment or that the environment is missing. That way you can deploy debug code and potentially remote debug it if need be.

Answer (score 1):

You may add trace and debug logs on your app. For ease, you may use logging frameworks like 
http://nlog-project.org/
https://serilog.net/

Comment: Where do I view the trace and debug logs on a live website?

Comment: You can configure n-log and serilog where to write logs.
see

 https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target

https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks

Answer (score 1):

You can actually write your own logging mechanism in which you can create a log class and some functions in it eg

```
 public class Log
    {

        internal static bool RecordLog(string strSource, string strMethodName, string strStatement)//additional params you think appropriate for your logs
        {


                List<string> lstInfo = new List<string>();

                string strProductName = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.ToString()).ProductName.ToString();
                string strProductVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.ToString()).ProductVersion.ToString();

                try
                {
                    strProductName = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location.ToString()).ProductName.ToString();
                    strProductVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location.ToString()).ProductVersion.ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                }

                try
                {
                    lstInfo.Add("** Date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMM yy, H:mm:ss") + ", " + strProductName + " v" + strProductVersion);
                    lstInfo.Add("Source=" + strSource + ", Server=" + strServerIP + ""); //add more info in list as per rquirement                  

                    bool flag = blnWriteLog("LogFilename",  lstInfo);
                }
                catch (Exception objEx)
                {
                 //exception handling 
                }

            return true;
        }

        private static bool blnWriteLog(string strProductName,  List<string> lstInfo)
        {
            string strPath = strGetLogFileName(strProductName);
            using StreamReader write in the log file received 

            return true;
        }

        private static string strGetLogFileName(string strFilePrefix)
        {
            //logic to check your file name, if it exists return name else create one 

            return strFile;

        }
    }
```

and then you can use the same from your file

```
Log.RecordLog()// Values as per your code and requirement
```

Note : Above is just a suggested way to do it, there can be many other and efficient ways also

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in Microsoft Intellitrace feature to step through code from the generated intellitrace logs. This link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449058.aspx gives instructions on how to achieve the following;

> "If you are using Microsoft Monitoring Agent to control IntelliTrace,
>   you also need to set up set up application performance monitoring on
>   your web server. This records diagnostic events while your app runs
>   and saves the events to an IntelliTrace log file. You can then look at
>   the events in Visual Studio Enterprise (but not Professional or
>   Community editions), go to the code where an event happened, look at
>   the recorded values at that point in time, and move forwards or
>   backwards through the code that ran. After you find and fix the
>   problem, repeat the cycle to build, release, and monitor your release
>   so you can resolve future potential problems earlier and faster."